# MYSQL Filter GROUP BY RESULT SET

Tags: mysql

Here is my query

```
SELECT user.id , user.first_name, GROUP_CONCAT(group.id SEPARATOR '###') AS sclr_129
FROM user 
    LEFT JOIN user_group  ON (user_group.user_id = user.id)
    INNER JOIN `group`  ON (user_group.group_id = group.id AND user_group.ug_status = 'Active' )
WHERE (user.first_name LIKE 'mike%' OR user.last_name LIKE 'Bulked%') 
GROUP BY user_group.user_id
LIMIT 25
```

Getting Result like this

```
Id |Name |sclr_129 
---------------------
52 |Mike |1###3###7
54 |Mike |2###4
57 |Mike |5
```

So basically trying to filter results by array of group ids.

So for example if i pass array [1,4] results will be filtered by existing group id, in this case

```
52 |Mike |1###3###7
```

will be return, despite 4 group id doesn't not belong to user. So user has one match group, return that group and all others.

My idea is to do that with sub query something like this.

```
SELECT user.id , user.first_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(group.id SEPARATOR '###') AS sclr_129
FROM user 
    LEFT JOIN user_group  ON (user_group.user_id = user.id)
    INNER JOIN `group`  ON (user_group.group_id = group.id AND user_group.ug_status = 'Active' AND group.id **NOT IN (SELECT id from `group` where id NOT IN (4))** )
WHERE (user.first_name LIKE 'mike%' OR user.last_name LIKE 'Bulked%') 
GROUP BY user_group.user_id
LIMIT 25
```

Any better ideas, added this line `AND group.id *NOT IN (SELECT id from`group`where id NOT IN (4))`*

Comment: I don't understand your question. If I guess it right - You just need a condition `AND user_group.group_id in (1, 4)` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: in that case 1 will be returned i want to return also 3, 7

Comment: thats why trying with NOT IN and subquery.